# Sorting in ascending order with selection sort

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm in need of big help, I cant seem to figure out how to do this code. So I am sorting an unsorted list of numbers in ascending order using selection sort and then returning the number of swaps it takes to sort the list.

Below is my code:

```
def swaps(numbers):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        minIndex = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(numbers)):
            if numbers[j] < numbers[minIndex]:
                minIndex = j
        if i != minIndex:
            numbers[i], numbers[minIndex] = numbers[minIndex], numbers[i]
            count += 1
    return count
```

For these two test cases:

```
numbers = [0, 4, 2, 7, 5]
print(swaps(numbers))

numbers = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
print(swaps(numbers))
```

it works perfect but for this test case it doesn't work:

```
import random

random.seed(30)

numbers = [random.randint(1, 50) for index in range(10)]

print(numbers)

print(swaps(numbers))
```

The numbers list for this test case is `[35, 19, 40, 2, 40, 42, 14, 17, 4, 26]`. Now working it out it swaps it 7 times but in my test program it is suppose to have swapped 8 times. Is this because of the repeat of `40` ?

How do I configure my code so that it takes into account a repeat of the same number?

Comment: "Now working it out it swaps it 7 times but in my test program it is suppose to have swapped 8 times." Do you mean that you *expect* 7, but that your code prints `8`? Because if so, when I run it, I get `7`, as expected.

Comment: And if it's the opposite and you expect 8 swaps (I can't quite tell from your phrasing), then I agree with Blckkght's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67313654/12975140). There's no need to swap 8 times with that input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are supposed to count an extra swap when you have a single pair of duplicate values, an easy way to match that expectation is to change the `numbers[j] < numbers[minIndex]` check to use `<=` instead of `<`.

That's making the code worse though, so I'd be sure to double check if that expectation is actually real or not. Managing to sort with fewer swaps should be a feature, not a bug!